# Clearcase Findmerge

Tags: clearcase

I want to find all the files that have been changed on a label (eg `label1`) from my view. `label1` Can be be applicable to multiple branches as well.

I tried following command, it did not work:

```
cleartool  findmerge . -fve "{lbtype(label 1)}" -print
```

What would be the correct command?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the files that are labelled '`label1`', a [`cleartool find`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) would be more adequate than [`cleartool findmerge`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-15).

```
cleartool find . –version 'lbtype(label1)' -print
```

For listing the files (and not their versions) on all branches:

```
cleartool find -all -element '{lbtype_sub(label1)}'
```

See also:

- "[Additional examples of the `cleartool find` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)"
- "[`cleartool find` examples](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm)"